# TypeError: int() argument must be a string a bytes-like object or a number not 'DataFrame'

Tags: python, pandas, tkinter

I having trouble passing a function as a parameter to another function. This is my code:

```
            sNummer = sv[9:11]
            pd.to_numeric(sNummer)
            print(type(sNummer))
            sNummer= df.replace(np.nan,0)
            sNummer= sNummer.replace(r'^\s*$', np.nan, regex=True)
            
            if int(sNummer) >= 0 and int(sNummer) <= 49:
                

                if gender.lower().strip() not in male_gender_options:
                    
                    #df= df.replace(r'^\s*$', np.nan, regex=True)
                    
                    df.at[index, 'sv_plausibility'] = (df.at[index,'sv_plausibility'].str.split()).apply(lambda x: float(sNummer))

                    if df.at[index, 'sv_plausibility'] == '':
                        df.at[index, 'sv_plausibility'] += 'Seriennummer müsste männlich sein aber passt nicht zu Geschlechtsspalte'
                    else:
                        df.at[index, 'sv_plausibility'] += ', Seriennummer müsste männlich sein aber passt nicht zu Geschlechtsspalte'

                else:
                    pass

            elif int(sNummer) >= 50 and int(sNummer) <= 99:

                if gender.lower().strip() not in female_gender_options:

                    if df.at[index, 'sv_plausibility'] == '':
                        df.at[index, 'sv_plausibility'] += 'Seriennummer müsste weiblich sein aber passt nicht zu Geschlechtsspalte'
                    else:
                        df.at[index, 'sv_plausibility'] += ', Seriennummer müsste weiblich sein aber passt nicht zu Geschlechtsspalte'

                else:
                    pass

            else:
                if df.at[index, 'sv_plausibility'] == '':
                    df.at[index, 'sv_plausibility'] += 'Seriennummer ungültig'
                else:
                    df.at[index, 'sv_plausibility'] += ', Seriennummer ungültig'
```

I don't understand because when i print the type of "sNummer" it's a string but somehow he says it's dataframe.

Any ideas?

the error:

here is the full traceback:

PART 2: PLAUSIBILITÄTSCHECK SV-Nr. <class 'datetime.datetime'> hr 1985-07-06 00:00:00 1985-07-06 00:00:00 1 3 1 Exception in Tkinter callback Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter_init_.py", line 1883, in call return self.func(*args) File "C:\Users\DE110117.spyder-py3\temp.py", line 1123, in run pwcDataCleaner().sv_nr_plausibility(df=excel_file, sv_column=self.svColumnName, gender_column=self.genderColumnName, File "C:\Users\DE110117.spyder-py3\temp.py", line 467, in sv_nr_plausibility if int(sNummer) >= 0 and int(sNummer) <= 49: TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'DataFrame'

sv: sv_column (index)

Comment: Please provide the full traceback, what is `sv` and what does `print(type(sNummer))` return. Also, why are you reassigning `sNummer` to `df.replace(np.nan,0)` when you already assigned that variable to `sv[9:11]`

Comment: df.replace(np.nan,0) i wanted to a df.replace to make the empty case with an N/A in this column precisely

Comment: yeah i replace it with the sNummer variable

Comment: Do you want this instead: `df = df.replace(...)`?

Comment: yeah like this https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html

Comment: May be you need `sNumber = pd.to_numeric(sNumber)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
sNummer = sv[9:11]
pd.to_numeric(sNummer)
```

When you created this variable, in order to pd.to_numeric work, Pandas converted sNummer to a Dataframe, so the type is dataframe.

Probably the dataframe created has just one value, that is the number that you want, you can print the entire sNummer to see the values that it has.

I think that instead of passing sNummer you could pass sNummer[0] to your function, and get the Int that it needs

Comment: yeah i know but i want to convert the dataframe into an float or an int directly but as we can see it doesn't work

Comment: i wanted that the mpty case are "N/A" and the case tht are not empty converted to float or string

Comment: this line doesn't work sNummer is still an string after

Answer (score 0):

```
            sNummer = sv[9:11]
            sNumber=pd.to_numeric(sNummer,errors='coerce')
            print(type(sNummer))
            
            if int(sNummer) >= 0 and int(sNummer) <= 49:
```

that's my new code but i have this error:

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

i think it's because some cases are empty and the line with "errors coerce" don't work